# Attempted import error: 'MapControl' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, draw

I tried using react-leaflet-draw and I keep on getting this error:

```
./node_modules/react-leaflet-draw/dist/esm/EditControl.js
Attempted import error: 'MapControl' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'.
```

I just used the examples here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-draw

Comment: that sounds like the project hasn't installed its dependencies properly? can you explain more what you've done and what doesn't work?

Comment: hmm I'll try to re-do the installation of dependencies again.

Comment: I resolved it when I installed the older version (2.7.0). I initially installed version 3.0 and I got problems in components naming convention. First is "Map". Resolved it by changing "Map" to "MapContainer". Second is "MapControl".  Maybe "MapControl" has new name in the latest version but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it is because MapControl is not part of react-leaflet lib anymore (https://react-leaflet-v2-docs.netlify.app/docs/en/components). Could you figure out its new name? Interested here!

Comment: I still can't figure it out. I just used the older version for the meantime.